# Animate metrics in Visual Format Language

Tags: ios, visual-format-language

Can you animate metrics in Visual Format Language? I have tried something like the following:

```
// ViewDidLoad
    self.padding = 100
    self.metrics = [:]
    self.metrics?["padding"] = 100

// And then in some method
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.metrics?["padding"] = 100
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```